# Jquery Radio Button On Posts

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hi I have a form that data post something weird...

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="datatype" value="1"/> <label>Datatype 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="datatype" value="2"/> <label>Datatype 2</label>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

FORM 1:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var dt = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        data: dt,
        ..................
    })
})
```

FORM 2:

```
  $('form').submit(function(){
    var opt = $(['input[name=datatype]').val();
    var dt = [{name:'dtype',value: opt }];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        data: dt,
        ..................
    })
})
```

In FORM 1 datatype properly post with the correct value either 1 or 2. In this part I am using serialize array. Now the weird thing is on FORM 2 if you choose datatype 2 it always post the value of 1. I need to use FORM 2 for some reason... Am glad if anyone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var opt = $('input[name=datatype]:checked').val();
    var dt = [{name:'dtype',value: opt }];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        data: dt,
        ..................
    })
})
```

---

#### Why your FORM2 code always get `1`

By default it get the value according to the order in DOM. As `radio` with `value="1"` comes first so it select the value `1`, though you select the `radio` with `value="2"`.

---

#### Correction to your code

Your `$(['input[name=datatype]').val();` statement is wrong. it should

`$('input[name=datatype]:checked').val();` which will get the value of checked `radio` button.

Your selector may also be:

```
$(':radio:checked[name=datatype]').val()
```

### **[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7DXeS/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

First, a square bracket opening is giving error that is closed no where.

And for your question, that is because, the DOM selects the element by name serially. Since the value 1 comes first, it is selected. So, you have to add a filter to select the one that is checked.

So, replace,

```
    var opt = $(['input[name=datatype]').val();
```

with

```
    var opt = $('input[name=datatype]:checked').val();
```